# The Sine Law: A Simplified Criterion for the Ambiguous Case?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Here is my suggestion for an issue that doesn't seem to be handled well in any online notes that I have seen. Can anyone give a counter-example?

> If you are given $a,b,$ and $B$ in $\triangle ABC$ (using the standard trig naming conventions) and you are using the Sine Law to solve for $A$ in $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}$, then you would have a so-called Ambiguous Case if and only if $b<a$.

In that case, calculate the first value $A_1=\sin^{-1}(\frac{a \cdot \sin B}{b})$. Calculate the second value $A_2=180^\circ - A_1$.

---

**Follow-up**

Based on discussions here and elsewhere, here is my corrected version of the criterion:

> If you are given $a,b,$ and $B$ in $\triangle ABC$ (using the standard trig naming conventions) and you are using the Sine Law to solve for $A$ in $\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}$, then you would obtain at least one solution  $A_1=\sin^{-1}(\frac{a \cdot \sin B}{b})$. And you would have a so-called Ambiguous Case if and only if $A_1\ne 90^\circ$ and $b\lt a$.

In that case, you would have a second solution  $A_2=180^\circ - A_1$.

Answer (score 3):

(2) is not unnecessary because if you don't have (2) then you can have that (3) is immpossible (if you have A > $90^\circ$ then $a$ will be largest side) and you have to have (4) because if you don't you can have A = $90^\circ$ witch by (2) is immposible.

Comment: Using the diagram at link, if $A>90^\circ$ then you will not have an ambiguous case.

Comment: Can you give a counter-example?

Comment: Yes and the criteria you posted have to be fulfilled for case to be ambiguous, and if you neglect (2) you can have non ambiguous cases.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Can you give an example of a triangle (as labelled at link) such that $a\geq c$ and we have an ambiguous case for $C$?

Comment: You can't and that is the point you can have ambiguous cases for C only if all those criteria are satisfied, but if you say that $a\geq c$ then it follows $A \geq C$ and then C is defind for only one value (it's non ambiguous).

Comment: Just to confirm, as labelled at link, you agree with me that $C$ is ambiguous if and only if $a\lt c$? Regardless of the value of $A$.

Comment: It's ambiguous if and only if a < c witch is equivalent with A < C, so it is not regardless of A.

Comment: Thanks. (I think you want to say "which" instead of "witch.") :^)

Comment: Thanks. English is not my first language so mistakes are bound to happen.